# Adding Tag On Single Post from bbpress (Tewenty Ten) Themes

Tags: theme-twenty-ten

i want adding tag on my single post, currently now i am using bbpress (Twent Ten) Themes,

What i want is include Taged With :

on a single post.

Thank You,

RA

Comment: Could you try to formulate your question more clearly? It is hard to understand what precisely you are asking.

Comment: Like : This entry was posted in Category Name. Tag With: Post Tag Bookmark the permalink. on single post blog page

Answer (score 0):

Use `bbp_topic_tag_list()` function, like this:

```
$args = array(
    'before' => '',
    'sep' => '',
    'after' => ''
);
bbp_topic_tag_list( '', $args );
```

Comment: What i want is  
Like : This entry was posted in Category Name. Tag With: Post Tag Bookmark the permalink. on single post blog page

Comment: @Ruly so you want it on a single blog post page or on a single topic page? If the former, what does it have to do with bbPress?